# Why isn't my negative number properly obtained in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodeJS to parse some HEX string, I am trying to convert the HEX value into a integer value using parseInt but I am running into some difficulties with the negative number that I don't understand the reason why.

I have the following HEX string `D3FFBDFFF900` that is ecoding the following integers `x:-0.45*100 y:-0.67*100 z:2.49*100` in the this way

`D3FF | BDFF | F900 => -0.45*100 | -0.64*100 | 2.49*100`

And I have created the following code snippet ( and I do now that the division by 100 is being missed there )

```js
var x = "D3FFBDFFF900".substring(0,4);
var y = "D3FFBDFFF900".substring(4,8);
var z = "D3FFBDFFF900".substring(8);

console.log("x:"+x);
console.log("y:"+y);
console.log("z:"+z);

console.log("parseInt x "+parseInt(x.toString(16),16));
console.log("parseInt y "+parseInt(y.toString(16),16));
console.log("parseInt z "+parseInt(z.toString(16),16));
```

Why isn't parseInt been able to decode at least the values x=-45, y=-67 and z=249 and instead I have the above output?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: the way of encoding the data is like below, where the print just print the original HEX string into a serial bus

```
#define NIBBLE_TO_HEX_CHAR(i) ((i <= 9) ? ('0' + i) : ('A' - 10 + i))
#define HIGH_NIBBLE(i) ((i >> 4) & 0x0F)
#define LOW_NIBBLE(i) (i & 0x0F)

 for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            print(static_cast<char>(NIBBLE_TO_HEX_CHAR(HIGH_NIBBLE(payload[i]))));
            print(static_cast<char>(NIBBLE_TO_HEX_CHAR(LOW_NIBBLE(payload[i]))));
        }
```

and the values `x,y,z` are got as below where type of `accelerometer.getX() -> double`

```
x = (int16_t)(accelerometer.getX()*100)
y = (int16_t)(accelerometer.getX()*100)
z = (int16_t)(accelerometer.getX()*100)
```

Comment: It is correctly parsing the numbers as hexadecimal. Either (a) the numbers are not encoded as hex or (b) you encoded them incorrectly

Comment: How are you getting the hex codes – are you encoding the literal equations, or the results of them?

Comment: @Quentin (a) the number are encoded as hex and (b) they are coded correctly becuase the HEX string is as expected

Comment: @Callam I am just encoding the result of them

Comment: @ndarkness — That's like saying that in `2 + 3 = 4` the 2 and 3 were added up correctly because the result is an integer as expected. Just because the result is is valid hex doesn't mean it is the result you expect. In particular, a negative number in hex still needs a minus symbol to indicate that it is a negative number.

Comment: It looks like the last 2 Hex characters of each encoded number has to be substracted from the first two. (`x = D3 - FF = 211 - 255 = -44`)

Comment: Why do you think that 0xD3FF equals -45? 15*1+15*16+3*256+13*4096=54271, -45=-0x2D

Answer (score 0):

How should the parser know, that you swapped the nibbles and use hex with 4 digits?

0xD3FF = 15 * 1 + 15 * 16 + 3 * 256 + 13 * 4096 = 54271

-45 = -0x2D

-67 = -0x43

249 = 0xF9

The parser does a correct job.

To parse the received hex values you have to swap the high and low nibbles:

D3FF => FFD3

Next you have to parse the hex to dec. If your value >= 0x8000 you have to invert the binary representation and add 1

0xFFD3 = 65491 > 0x8000 = 32768

-(~65491 & 0xFFFF) + 1 = -43